# How to Fix Xamarin Runtime Error "System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop"

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I Created a new Blank Android Project on Visual Studio 2015 and when i tried to Run that, it threw an Exception that "System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop" and the solution is looking for a file named "AndroidRuntime.cs" in this adress: "/Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs"

my OS is Windows 7 64bit and i`v already installed this Tools:

• JDK 7 update 7.1

• Xamarin Visual Studio 4.1.0.530

• Xamarin Studio 6.0.0.5174-0

• Android NDK r11c

• Latest version of Android SDKs

Answer (score 0):

After I installed the latest Xamarin components (Xamarin 4.1.0.530 / Xamarin.Android 6.1.0.71), my projects started showing "Module: Java.Interop...should be referenced" warnings/errors.

Adding a reference to the Xamarin Java.Interop assembly resolved this issue for me.

Also, make sure you have installed the latest Xamarin.Android package.

Hope this solves your issue as well.